# Even/Odd Shading Based on ID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm new to SharePoint and trying to create a view on a list where it will only display the records, with odd ID numbers.

I created the following .css script and added it using Content Editor:
style type = "text/css">
.ms-alternating {background-color: #FF0000;}

However the issue I'm running into, is that if there is a list of 10 items, if item number 6 gets pulled into another list (original list is used as staging area), then what was once colored, will no longer be colored.  I am looking for a solution that would be dependent on the ID, so that the color will be static on each file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript with **Client Side Rendering** to render rows based on ID in the list view.

Check if the ID is Even or Odd number by dividing the ID number by 2 (`ID % 2`). % will give the remainder value. If the remainder is 0 (zero) then it is an Even number, otherwise it is an Odd number.

If ID is Even number (or Odd number, per your requirement), set this row color (`tr.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";`)

**Demos** about how to color rows in list view based on the conditions with Client Side Rendering:

[Rendering list view using Client Side Rendering](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

[SharePoint 2013 Conditional formatting in list views](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-conditional-formatting-in-listviews/)